# Error when I click on "add other" in open source section in CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Every time I click "other" from "add or update" in open source section in CV, I am redirected to an error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small glitch on our end, sorry about that.

Fixed.